# page-based app with uitableview; how to show detail view and show another data in the table when goes to next page?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have page-based app. On each page I have 3 uibuttons at the top, uiscrollview with alphabet (uibuttons to sort data in uitable) at the right and uitableview at the center. How to show cell's detail view? If it is necessary to add uinavigationcontroller I can't do this. If I adds it, it disables interaction with my table, buttons and scrollview.
And another question is how to show new data in tableview and scrollview when goes to next page??

I have rootViewController class and DataViewController class.
rootViewController listing:

```
@interface RootViewController ()
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) ModelController *modelController;
@end

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize pageViewController = _pageViewController;
@synthesize modelController = _modelController;
@synthesize navContr = _navContr;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
// Configure the page view controller and add it as a child view controller.

//[self presentModalViewController:navContr animated:YES];

self.pageViewController = [[[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil] autorelease];
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

DataViewController *startingViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:0 storyboard:self.storyboard];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];

   self.pageViewController.dataSource = self.modelController;

[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

self.navContr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.navContr.view];


// Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
CGRect pageViewRect = self.view.bounds;
self.pageViewController.view.frame = pageViewRect;

[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

// Add the page view controller's gesture recognizers to the book view controller's view so that the gestures are started more easily.
self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers){
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]){
        [recognizer setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
}
```

---

After few manipulations it works but I need help to get it work fine!

So now it looks like this

[image: one] [image: two]

Next question: how do I remove the brown space at the top???

---

::UPDATE::

Problem solved. It needs just to set y-axis position of UINavigationController to -20 ;)

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways but by far the easiest way is to use a navigation controller.  In fact, it is built to do exactly this.

If you don't want the navigationBar then you can hide it in the viewWillAppear function.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Then you can add an other UIViewController to push when the user selects a cell.

Having read your OP again I'm not sure how you are adding your navigationController.

To use a navigationController you create it and load it at start time.  You then create your current viewController (the one with the buttons and table etc...) and set this as the rootViewController of the navigationController.

Then you display the navigationController.

Could you explain how you are adding your navigationController as it may help understand what is going wrong.

Thanks

::EDIT::

OK, my assumption was correct.

The way you are using the navigation controller is not how it was intended.

OK, so at the moment your AppDelegate file will have a method Application didFinishLaunching...

It will look something like this...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[OJFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

You should change it so that it is like this...

first add a property to your appDelegate...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Then change the didFinishLaunchingMethod to this...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[OJFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This will still show you MainViewController but it will now be contained within a navigationController.

Next in your MainViewController function `viewWillAppearAnimated` add the line...

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
```

This will then hide the navigationBar at the top of the view so you still have access to your buttons.

The you need a new ViewController and xib file (for example DetailViewController).

When the user selects a table row you need to then do something like...

```
DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

//pass in details of which row was selected.

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

This will then display your new view and new viewController.  You will also need to write a way of passing the data in (set up a property on the DetailViewController).

Hope this helps.

Comment: method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is empty. All controllers creates in rootVievController.m. And I think I have to change this class to get nedeed result.

Comment: OK, in the build settings you'll have an option something like Main Interface.  Remove whatever is in that option and write the AppDelegate method as above.  Use RootViewController in place of MainViewController.  Basically you need to set you RootViewController as the rootViewController of a navigationController.

Comment: if I do this my functionality will get lost. I don't know how to make pages with flipping. And in the build settings there is no Main interface or similar.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this link about creating navigation-based project may help you.. (http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2012/08/navigation-based-project-doing-it.html)

From that tutorial, there's a class called SampleViewController, subclass of UIViewController. You might want to put a tableView in SampleViewController.xib file. Then in your SampleViewController.h file, add an IBOutlet UITableView* yourTable property and synthesize it. Connect it to your tableView in your .xib file. //Or you may do it programmatically

in your SampleViewController.h, make your interface header look like this.. I think you already know this...

@interface SampleViewController:UIViewController < UITableviewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource >

in your SampleViewcontroller.m, under viewDidLoad method, set the table delegate and datasource to self:

```
yourTableView.delegate = self;
yourTableView.datasource = self;
```

Afterwhich, you implement tableView delegate and datasource methods... //you already know those since you were already able to show a tableview ;)

**one of these methods is the "tableview:didSelectAtIndexpath:" --> this is the part wherein you can put your code when you click one of the cells.**

Let's assume you have the DetailsViewController Class, this is the class you would like to show after clicking a cell and show its details.

DetailsViewController Class must have a variable that will accept the data you would like to show. Let's say, an NSString *detailsMessage; //do the @property and @synthesize thing...

Let's go back to SampleViewController.m file, under tableview:didSelectAtIndexpath: Method:
inside that Method.. put these codes.

```
DetailsViewController *detailsVC = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
detailsVC.detailsMessage = @"The Data you want to pass.";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsVC animated:YES];
```

I hope this helps. :(

Comment: thank you! I know how to create uitable, set the delegates and call method didSelectRowAtIndexPath. And also I know how to work with uinavigationcontroller. But I don't know how to add it to my project based on pagecontroller :(((

Comment: oops my bad.. I'm sorry i couldn't be of any help. :(